# How to cheaply melt many micro UTXOs?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, utxo, micropayments, consolidation

I know this was probably brought up before but I cannot find any good resources on some potential, at least theoretical way of achieving this.

So basically I have a lot of UTXOs whose value is between lets say 1k sats and 5k sats and I want to transfer them all into a single UTXO.

With current fee rates of 15sats/byte I would barely break even in the best case scenario.

Is there any strategy or algorithm that could help with this kind of issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no free lunch.  You can spend all the UTXOs in one transaction to spread the output bytes across many inputs, but each input still needs a certain number of bytes.  To my knowledge, there isn't any more efficient way of spending them than the standard transaction types.  (If there were, *it* would be the standard.)

You can of course attach a fee below the current prevailing rate, and hope that the transaction gets picked up during some period of low transaction demand (when fees drop), or wait until such a time to broadcast your transaction.  Certain times of day or days of the week may be somewhat better; you could look back at historical transaction fees to get a sense.  But there's no guarantee that such a low-fee transaction will get confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your time-restraints, you either have to pay the market's current fee rate, or wait until the block space demand is low enough to include your transaction at a much lower fee rate. [Nate did a good job at describing that.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/80220/5406)

I wanted to add that there is an on-going discussion to generally lower the `minFeeRate`, so if you can be very patient, your transaction may eventually relay and get mined even paying a fee rate below 1 satoshi per byte. See: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/13922, https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/13990